# How to make snake move faster in snake game?

Tags: vb.net

I want to snake move faster after it eats, for example, 10 "mouses". How can I do that or where`s problem in my code?

```
Private Sub snake_Moves_Faster()

    If lenghtofsn = lenghtofsn + 10 Then

        tm_SnakeMover.Interval = tm_SnakeMover.Interval - 5

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub tm_SnakeMover_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tm_SnakeMover.Tick

    For i = lenghtofsn To 1 Step -1
        snake(i).Top = snake(i - 1).Top
        snake(i).Left = snake(i - 1).Left
    Next

    Label2.Text = ("0")
    If snake(0).Bounds.IntersectsWith(mouse.Bounds) Then
        Label2.Text = CStr(CInt(Label2.Text)) + 1
    End If
    collideWithMouse()
    snake(0).Top += udMover
    snake(0).Left += lrMover
    Collide_with_walls()
    snake_Moves_Faster()
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is in this line: `If lenghtofsn = lenghtofsn + 10 Then`. What does that compare to what else? Can you see why that would never evaluate to True?

Comment: @AndrewMorton In fact, i am new in programming and no i can`t see that. I can show you full code

Comment: From your description, what you need to check for is `If lenghtofsn = 10 Then`. You want to compare the length of the snake to 10, not to 10 more than the length of the snake. (P.S. It's best to spell things correctly in code, so the variable name would be more like `lengthOfSn` as lowerCamelCase is the usual format for variables in VB.NET. Many other things, like class and method names, use UpperCamelCase. "House" styles may be different.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks. My description was little incorrect. I want every time a snake eats 10 "Mouses", speed increases. P.S. sorry if i`m writing incorrectly. I don`t know english very well.

Comment: One way: add 1 to a counter variable every time a mouse is eaten. When that number gets to 10, increase the snake speed and reset the counter to 1.